# Recharts Line activeDot function breaks tooltip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to trigger a function based on the activeDot of a Line in Recharts.

With the default value of `true`, moving the mouse around the chart shows the default tooltip, a vertical highlighted gridline, and the dots on the line are made larger, as expected.

However, say I want to trigger an event with the payload from the activeDot:

```
  activeDotHandler(data) {
    this.setState({ dotData: data }); // to be used in a different part of the webpage
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LineChart ...>
        <XAxis ... />
        <YAxis ... />

        <Tooltip />

        <Line activeDot={this.activeDotHandler.bind(this)} ... />

      </LineChart>
    );
  }
```

This works, but the tooltip and highlighted line no longer show up like when you have `activeDot={true}`.

Returning `true` from the function also doesn't work.

I've tried things like `activeDot={{ onMouseOver: this.activeDotHandler.bind(this) }}` but then the mouse must be directly over the dot.

I just want the default tooltip and activeDot functionality with the addition of an event with the activeDot's payload.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**: I also tried adding `onMouseOver` to the `<LineChart>` itself, which helpfully gave me an event containing the payload of the active point. However, that STILL disables the default tooltip/highlighted grid/activedot styling.

**EDIT 2**: Also tried returning the `<circle>` after `this.setState()`. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recharts Line activeDot function with custom tooltip

Have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/recharts-issue-activedot-forked-k8norr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)!

https://codesandbox.io/embed/recharts-issue-activedot-forked-k8norr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).